# Show that a complex number is on a line.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $v$ and $w$ be  two distinct complex numbers such that $v + t (w-v)$ is a line $l$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that:

If $\frac{z - w}{z-v}$ is a real number, for instance $t$, then $z$ is on the line $l$.

I have already tried using the hint as follows:

\begin{equation}
\frac{z - w}{z-v}=t 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z - w=t(z-v) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z = \frac{-v t +w}{1-t} 
\end{equation}

This doesn't really get me anywhere, at least I think it doesn't because I don't recognise the form of my desired line in here. I also tried using the following algorithm:
\begin{equation}
\frac{z - w}{z-v}(w-v)=t(w-v) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{z - w}{z-v}(w-v)+v=v+ t(w-v) 
\end{equation}
Which can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{zw-w^2 +vw-v^2}{z-v}=v+ t(w-v) 
\end{equation}

I would have hoped it to simplify to $z$. Do you people have any pointers or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation
$$
z = \frac{-v t +w}{1-t} 
$$
can be written as
$$
z=v+\tau(w-v),
$$
where $\displaystyle\tau={1\over1-t}={z-v\over w-v}$.

Comment: $v+t(w-v)=wt+v(1-t)$. I edited my answer to show that more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for alternate solution: Think geometrically. We have that $l$ is the line going through the points $v$ and $w$ in the complex plane. What can you say about two complex numbers (interpreted as vectors in the plane) if their ratio (as complex numbers) is real?

Comment: This means that they are parallel.

Comment: Later in the same exercise I can use this fact to prove that $(z-w)(\bar{z}-\bar{v})= (\bar{z} - \bar{w})(z-v)$ if and only if $v, w, z$ are collinear.

Comment: Divide that relation by $(\bar z-\bar w)(z-w)$, and you get that one side is the conjugate of the other, meaning they are real, and thus you can use the result from this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had already used it, without knowing why it was true haha :P

Answer (score 1):

Just one more step.

$$z=\frac{-vt+w}{1-t}=v+\frac{w-v}{1-t}=v+t'(w-v)$$

with $t'=\frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: Thanks :) that did the trick!